# Spaces in string causing fatal error: cannot increment beyond endIndex

Tags: string, macos, substring, swift3

I have a string "PIXEL STUDIOS - TEST1"  My code works until I reach the first space in the string.

```
var str = label.stringValue

        let c = str.characters

        let r = c.index(c.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)..<c.index(c.endIndex, offsetBy: 0)

        let substring = str[r]

        print(substring)
```

When I run my code and offsetBy 5 it works but when I try to offset past that point I get the error.  Is there something else I need to do to handle spaces in my string?

Comment: In Swift 3 you can reduce the code a lot : `let r = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)..<str.endIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working with the given string:

```
var str =  "PIXEL STUDIOS - TEST1"
let c = str.characters
let r = c.index(c.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)..<c.index(c.endIndex, offsetBy: 0)
let substring = str[r]
print(substring)
```

prints:

```
STUDIOS - TEST1
```

Conclusion: `label.stringValue` is fishy.

Print it out for further investigations.

Comment: Hmm well unfortunately I need to use label.stringValue because that string is being passed in via JSON from a database.  I cant use the literal string.  Is there any fix for this?

Comment: That is no problem. Print out `label`and `label.stringValue`.

Comment: Well when I print out "label" I get something like this: "<NSTextField: 0x6180001e4500>"  When I print out label.stringValue: "PIXEL STUDIOS - TEST1"

Comment: try to cast it to string: `var str = label.stringValue as! String`

Comment: Unfortunately...still the same result.  I guess I will need to try and cut my string in my PHP if I cant do it in swift.  Another swift3 fail!

Comment: I assume it contains a "weired" whitespace character. Too early to blame Swift 3.

Comment: I tried trimming whitespaces too and still got the same result.  But ya thanks for helping me out.  I appreciate the effort.

Comment: how does the string look after trimming whitespaces. I assume the space at index 5 is the weired whitespace.

Comment: It is still the same result.  trimming the whitespace has no effect.  It has something to do with it being label.stringValue and not a literal string.  But I feel like anyone creating a dynamic application isn't going to be using literal strings for their data so this is definitely an issue lol.

Comment: Everybody uses labels all the time. "1234" is just a short form to initialize a `String`. It is not a C literal string. Something is wrong with the Character number 5.

Comment: Of what type is `label`?

Comment: it is a NSTextField